# Collision detection between rectangle and arrow

Tags: collision-detection, collision

I want to detect collision between a rectangle and an arrow. What is the best algorithm or method for that?

I tried to implement Separating Axis Theorem but for following case i get collision = true which is wrong.

[image]

Also, is an arrow a convex polygon?

Thanks for help.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arrow is [concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_%28disambiguation%29).

The easiest way to do this would probably be to treat the arrow as two separate shapes: a rectangle and a triangle. Checking for a rectangle-to-rectangle collision is pretty easy, and for the triangle (which *is* convex) you could use whatever code you have for checking against convex polygons. If either returns true for collision, return true; otherwise, return false.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for help. I got confused with convex and concave polygons and so it didn't work. I worked out as you suggested and everything worked properly. Thanks a lot. Regards